# after successful ajax retry no .done

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm making a request to a php file. The response is processed in .done(function(msg){}); and .fail this works fine. But sometimes the request gets an error. I made a retry for this. The retry also works. But if the first time fails and it is successful in de 2 or 3 try my request.done doesn't fire (in firebug I can see that is was successful)

My request:

```
    var request = $.ajax({    
                url:            "wcf.php",            
                type:           "POST",     
                dataType:       "xml",
                async:          false,
                timeout:        5000,
                tryCount:       0,
                retryLimit:     3,
                data:      { barcode: value, curPrxID: currentPrxID, timestamp: (new Date).getTime()},
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    if (xhr.status == 500) {
                        alert('Server error');
                    } 
                        this.tryCount++;
                        if (this.tryCount < this.retryLimit) {
                            $.ajax(this);
                            //return;
                        }
                }
           }) ;
```

And this is the .done and fail:

```
request.done(function(msg) 
{
    $(msg).find("Response").each(function()
    {
             // my code here
    });
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
{ 
    $("#message").html(errorThrown);    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.done()` and `.fail()` methods are part of [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) which is implemented in the `jqXHR` object returned by `$.ajax()`. Callbacks which you register with them are not part of  `$.ajax()` options so you can't pass them to another `$.ajax()`. In your code you are subscribing only to parent `$.ajax()` *Deferred Object* callbacks. To achieve the result you want, you should wrap entire operation in another *Deferred Object* and use `.resolveWith()`/`.rejectWith()` methods to pass the proper context. Also you need to remember that *Deferred Object* can change its state to *resolved* or *rejected* only once (in another words if it fails it can't succeed later). So the final code might look like this:

```
var request = $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
    $.ajax({    
        url: 'wcf.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        async: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        tryCount: 0,
        retryLimit: 3,
        data: { barcode: value, curPrxID: currentPrxID, timestamp: (new Date).getTime()},
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            if (xhr.status == 500) {
                alert('Server error');
            }
            this.tryCount++;
            if (this.tryCount < this.retryLimit) {
                $.ajax(this).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    deferred.resolveWith(this, [data, textStatus, jqXHR]);
                }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (this.tryCount >= this.retryLimit) {
                        deferred.rejectWith(this, [jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown]);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        deferred.resolveWith(this, [data, textStatus, jqXHR]);
    });
}).promise();

request.done(function(msg) {
    $(msg).find("Response").each(function() {
        //Success code here
    });
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    $("#message").html(errorThrown);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! didn't think of it this way.